# How do I open the cells around a user picked cell in in minesweeper

Tags: c#

[image]I need to open the cells around a user picked cell in my rendition of minesweeper using C#. A user enters a coordinate I.e. 1, 3 and the program " opens" the cell and it either displays a number which indicates the bombs around it or its an empty field (Like minesweeper!). How should I appproach solving this problem so the cell and every cell near it open if empty?

```
//Opens cells if there is no bomb 
        public bool Open(int row, int column)
        {
            bool result = false;
            if (row >= 0 && row < Dimension && column >= 0 && column < Dimension)
            {
                if (!cells[row, column].Open)
                {
                    cells[row, column].Open = true;

                    result = true;
                }

            }

            return result;
        }
```

'''

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution is to recursively call your Open function for each neighboring cell. Since Open function already checks for invalid/open cells, no need to pre-check before recursive call.

```
if (cells[row, column].Empty)
{
    Open(row - 1, column - 1);
    Open(row - 1, column);
    Open(row - 1, column + 1);
    Open(row, column - 1);
    Open(row, column + 1);
    Open(row + 1, column - 1);
    Open(row + 1, column);
    Open(row + 1, column + 1);
}
```

If non-recursive method is desired, you could use something like breadth-first search

```
public bool Open(int row, int column)
{
    bool result = false;
    if (row >= 0 && row < Dimension && column >= 0 && column < Dimension)
    {
        if (!cells[row, column].Open)
        {
            cells[row, column].Open = true;

            if (cells[row, column].Empty)
            {
                var bfs = new Queue<(int Row, int Column)>()
                bfs.Enqueue((row, column));
                while (bfs.Count > 0)
                {
                    (int r, int c) = bfs.Dequeue();
                    int rb = r - 1;
                    if (rb < 0) rb = r;
                    int re = r + 1;
                    if (re >= Dimension) re = r;
                    int cb = c - 1;
                    if (cb < 0) cb = c;
                    int ce = c + 1;
                    if (ce >= Dimension) ce = c;
                    for (int i = rb; i <= re; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = cb; j <= ce; j++)
                        {
                            if (!cells[i, j].Open)
                            {
                                cells[i, j].Open = true;
                                if (cells[i, j].Empty) bfs.Enqueue((i, j));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            result = true;
        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: _"no issue of calling the Open function multiple times for the same cell"_. It would be even better if you show OP how to avoid that

Comment: This solution does hold the possibility of resulting in a stack overflow error

Comment: @Khyran yes, recursive functions tend to cause stack overflow error if not managed correctly. In this case, a) I don't think that would be much of an issue and b) a recursive function is much simpler to program compared to other methods, such as search functions like [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (which hold the possibility of resulting in out-of-memory error if not properly managed).